# ngrx normalized state selector

Tags: ngrx, normalizr

I'm rewriting a Ionic project to work with ngrx because it is growing a lot and I need to maintain a centralized state.

I have implemented it with ngrx and using normalized states with the help of Normalizr.

Now I have a doubt on how to pass to dumb component a populated object:

Suppose I have two interfaces:

```
interface Conversation {
    date: Date,
    lastMessage: string //this is the id of a message entity coming from normalizr
}
```

and

```
 interface Message {
       content: string
}
```

Now when I'm trying to get all conversations to pass to the dumb component I'm using a selector like this:

```
getConversations() {

    //select all the conversations to have a shape of Conversation[]
    let conversations$ = this.store.select(state => Object.keys(state.entities.conversations).map( (id:string) => state.entities.conversations[id] ));

    //select all the messages in a shape { [id:string] : Message }
    let messages$ = this.store.select(state => state.entities.messages);

    return Observable.combineLatest(
      conversations$,
      messages$,
      (conversations, messages) => {
        return conversations.map(conversation => {
          return { ...conversation, lastMessage: messages[conversation.lastMessage] }

        });
      }
    )
  }
```

But the Observable I'm returning is not an array of Conversation[] because

```
return { ...conversation, lastMessage: messages[conversation.lastMessage] }
```

is putting inside 'lastMessage' an object of type Message instead of a String.

I tried to use interfaces with the object type instead of strings

```
interface Conversation {
       date: Date,
       lastMessage: Message
    }
```

But then I cannot use selector like

```
this.store.select(state => state.entities.messages[conversation.lastMessage]
```

because it is not a string anymore.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this question would be the following:

You need to select the `content` property from the last message, as in:

```
return { ...conversation, lastMessage: messages[conversation.lastMessage].content }
```

The longer answer:

The same can be achieved with selectors, this has the benefit that it's more re-usable in comparison with the RxJS operators.

> A selector is a pure function that takes the state as an argument and
>   returns a slice of the store’s state. Instead of just returning the
>   data stored in the store, a selector can compute derived data based on
>   the available data. This allows you to only store the basics, keeping
>   the state tree as compact as possible. Another important part is that
>   selectors could be composed, that is: a selector can take one or
>   multiple other selectors as its input.

For example:

```
// getters
export const selectUser = (state: AppState) => state.selectedUser;
export const selectAllBooks = (state: AppState) => state.allBooks;

// create a selector with `createSelector` and use the getters above
export const selectVisibleBooks = createSelector(
  selectUser,
  selectAllBooks,
  (selectedUser: User, allBooks: Books[]) => {
    if (selectedUser && allBooks) {
      return allBooks.filter((book: Book) => book.userId === selectedUser.id);
    } else {
      return allBooks;
    }
  }
);
```

In your component to select select the books, you can do:

```
this.books = this.store.pipe(select(selectVisibleBooks));
```

More info:

- [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors)
- [Sharing data between modules is peanuts - A dive into NgRx selectors](https://blog.angularindepth.com/sharing-data-between-modules-is-peanuts-3f40fcb38dd)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. My question is more about typescript’s typings. Normalized entities has a string (which is the id of the related object) instead the full object inside. So I wrote all my entities with string fields instead Message for example. But when I’m using selectors for retrieving populated conversation to pass to dumb component it is not a Conversation type anymore, because in lastMessage filed there is not a string anymore, there is a Message type.