# NGRX Selector that transforms the state into other objects results in an ExpressionHasChanged exception

Tags: angular, ngrx

After [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581532/ngrx-how-to-have-calculated-properties-on-items-in-the-store) we've gone in and changed our selectors to return the "rich" objects.
So, our NGRX Entity states contains basic JavaScript objects, but we have state selectors that return rich objects.

Relevant code snippets in our selector:

```
const getAllAssets = createSelector(
  getAssetsState,
  getAllAssetModels,
  (state: AssetsState, assets) => {
    // if we just return assets, no error occurs(!)
    return assets.map(a => createAsset(a));    
  }
);
```

In the component HTML:

```
<ab-assets
  data-test-id="data-filter"
  [assets]="assets$ | async"></ab-assets>
```

and component TS:

```
assets$: Observable<Asset[]>;
```

...

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.assets$ = this.store.pipe(
     select(AssetsSelectors.assetsQuery.getAllAssets)
   );
 }
```

This all works fine, but we get the famous ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has 
changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'allData: [object Object]'. 
Current value: 'allData: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]'.
```

The .map() function seems to be the issue, when I just return the assets array it works fine.

@timdeschryver has replied with a very similar approach in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791561/ngrx-normalized-state-selector), so I'm not sure why it's not working?

However, when I not create a new array, but modify the existing one, it works fine:

```
for (let i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
  assets[i] = createAsset(assets[i]);
}    
return assets;
```

So the key question is: Why do I get an ExpressionHasChanged error when I return a new array?

Comment: Can you share how you're using the result in the typescript and template? I believe that's where the issue will be seen.

Comment: @OneLunchMan thank you, I've just added the HTML + TS of the component, thanks

Comment: see my answer, excluding the state from the selector is the solution. Still weird though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not the .map(), but the fact I was also retrieving the state in the selector.

So, this works:

```
const getAllAssets = createSelector(
  getAllAssetModels, assets => {
  return assets.map(a => createAsset(a));
});
```

This won't work:

```
const getAllAssets = createSelector(
  getAssetsState,
  getAllAssetModels, (state, assets) => {
  return assets.map(a => createAsset(a));
});
```

Still feels wrong to me...